# Python - plot numpy array with gaps in the data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to plot some spectral data as a 2D image, where each data point corresponds to a spectrum with a specific date/time. I require to plot all spectra as follows:
- xx-axis - corresponds to the wavelenght
- yy-axis - corresponds to the date/time
- intensity - corresponds to the flux

If my datapoints were continuous/sequential in time I would just use matplotlib's imshow. However, not only the points are not all continuous/sequential in time but I have large time gaps between points.

here is some simulated data that mimics what I have:

```
import numpy as np

sampleSize = 100

data={}
for time in np.arange(0,5):
    data[time] = np.random.sample(sampleSize)

for time in np.arange(14,20):
    data[time] = np.random.sample(sampleSize)

for time in np.arange(30,40):
    data[time] = np.random.sample(sampleSize)


for time in np.arange(25.5,35.5):
    data[time] = np.random.sample(sampleSize)

for time in np.arange(80,120):
    data[time] = np.random.sample(sampleSize)
```

if I needed to print only one of the subsets of data above; i would do:

```
mplt.imshow([data[time] for time in np.arange(0,5)], cmap ='Greys',aspect='auto',origin='lower',interpolation="none",extent=[-50,50,0,5])

mplt.show()
```

however, I have no idea how I can print all data in the same plot, while showing the gaps and keeping the yy-axis as the time. Any ideas?

thanks,
Jorge

Comment: `imshow` uses equal spacing between its pixels. You can use `pcolormesh` instead and define the x and y arrays to your desire.

Comment: @BillChen: Please see in the question the arrays generated

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: cool, thanks, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `pandas` to help you with sorting the keys, then `reindex`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
plt.imshow(df.reindex(np.arange(df.index.max())),
           cmap ='Greys',
           aspect='auto',
           origin='lower',
           interpolation="none",
           extent=[-50,50,0,5])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hum, that might be good as well. Will it work if the keys are not integers or have negative values?

Comment: Probably not for non integers, in which case, color mesh is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up using a different approach:

1) re-index the time in my data so that no two arrays has the same time and I avoid non-integer indexes

```
nTimes = 1
timeIndexes=[int(float(index)) for index in data.keys()]
while len(timeIndexes) != len(set(timeIndexes)):
    nTimes += 1
    timeIndexes=[int(nTimes*float(index)) for index in data.keys()]

timeIndexesDict = {str(int(nTimes*float(index))):data[index] for index in data.keys()}
lenData2Plot = max([int(key) for key in timeIndexesDict.keys()])
```

2) create an array of zeros with the number of columns like my data and a number of rows corresponding to my maximum re-indexed time

```
data2Plot = np.zeros((int(lenData2Plot)+1,sampleSize))
```

3) replace the rows in my array of zeros corresponding to my re-indeed times

```
for index in timeIndexesDict.keys():
    data2Plot[int(index)][:] = timeIndexesDict[str(index)]
```

4) plot as I normally would plot an array with no gaps

```
mplt.imshow(data2Plot,
            cmap='Greys',aspect='auto',origin='lower',interpolation="none",
       extent=[-50,50,0,120])
mplt.show()
```